# What kind of documentation is architecture documentation?

Tags: architecture, documentation

There is this [really amazing talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4vKPhjcMZg) about dividing Documentation into 4 different categories:

- **tutorials**: For learning
- **howtos**: To solve specific problems
- **references**: To provide information
- **explanations**: To help understand the bigger picture

There is also a writeup available here: https://documentation.divio.com/

So given a Software project (like emacs, django or numpy), where would documentation about the architecure fit in? Which directory should I put the [arc42](https://arc42.org/) or [C4model](https://c4model.com/) documents in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the same structure, I think it fits into the `explanations` category, given that architecture documents expose a high level view of the system.

As a general note, I think it's (maybe more) important to think about the way the doc maps into the ecosystem of the project, and try to make sure that the doc is always:

- Easily accessible by either developers or stakeholders
- Properly referenced in relevant places
- As up to date as possible

Structure is important, but optimising on those 3 vectors would bring more value to it, IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that the structure is what is helping me to optimise these vectors.